# Run-time error: Select method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, range, excel-2010

I am currently in Excel 2010 and created this spreadsheet and code in this version. My colleagues (using the spreadsheet) are using Excel 2007 (haven't been upgraded yet). They are getting the error message but I am not.

I had the following code set up so that based upon the selection in the `ComboBox`, the specified cells would populate with "N/A" or remain/become blank.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSite6_Change()

If ComboBoxSite6.Value = "N/A" Then
Range("Site6Cells").Select
Selection = "N/A"
Else
If ComboBoxSite6.Value <> "N/A" Then
Range("Site6Cells").Select **This line highlights with the error when debugged
Selection = ""
End If
End If

End Sub
```

The change of the combobox and the population (or not) of "N/A" is all happening with the same sheet of the workbook so that shouldn't be a problem. But even so, I tried adding the following before each of the "Range..." lines: Sheets("Site Prep"). This did not work either.

Additionally, I have 5 other columns and comboboxes doing the same action, coded in the same way prior to this piece of code and there are no problems indicated.

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?  Is this a backwards compatability issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the Range called "Site6Cells" doesn not exist in the right way.

Named ranges can be either global (= member of the whole workbook) or local (= member of the worksheet). If the Named range you created is a local one than you cannot call it as if it were a global one.

Check this via the ribbon for Formulas > Name Manager > Property called Scope

Compare this with that for your collegues and see if this is different.

To change it you will have to recreate it (delete the old ane, make a new one), or use a 3rd party Name manager, or change the scope via VBA.